# Can a Halfling Sling Staff double as a Staff?

Tags: weapons, pathfinder-2e

I don't see anything in AoN's description of the [Halfling Sling Staff](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=78) that says so, but the abilities of the [Staff Acrobat archetype](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=37) seem to imply that a Halfling Sling Staff doubles as a Staff to some degree ([Leveraging Strike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1196)  and [Pivot Strike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1198) especially).

Can a Halfling Sling Staff also function as a Staff? I believe in Pathfinder 1e it could be used as a club, but I'm not sure if that has been brought over into Pathfinder 2e.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### I'm going to go with yes.

The Halfling Sling Staff's description it

> **This staff** ends in a Y-shaped split that cradles a sling.

Furthermore, we already have [other items](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=754) that 'count as' staves for attacking. Finally, the [staff weapon](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=12) is cost 0, meaning it's basically any stick you pick up from the ground that is long enough.

For these reasons, although it is never detailed explicitly, I would say* the HSS should also be usable *as a staff*.

That being said, because there is nothing about the archetype that requires melee Strikes, RAW you could use the HSS' ranged attacks with its feats. You may not be able to use some of its effects (such as Pivot Strike's Shove or Trip) if you do not meet the other requirements of the action(s).

*GM's are of course under no requirement to agree with me, especially since the archetype is valid without this determination.

Answer (score 3):

For those specific feats, technically [a strike can be melee or ranged](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=321), so both feats work at range with this weapon.

With regards to the question in your title; 'Can a Halfling Sling Staff double as a Staff?'

Rules as Written (RAW), no you can't; you'd use it to make a ranged strike in melee, potentially causing [an attack of opportunity](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=145), if a creature has that ability, and is also in range. Or possibly a GM might allow you to consider it [an improvised weapon](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=224) which would allow you to make melee attacks with it, without provoking, but at a -2 item penalty -- however that would raise the question of if you could apply the weapons runes or not, and RAW, I suspect not.

The only slight exception is that the feats that are part of the [Staff Acrobat Archetype](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=37) can refer to it as a Staff: '(referred to in this archetype as “your staff”)'. To me that is pretty clear in that it doesn't make it a staff -- it doesn't also let you treat a Spear as a staff.

As a GM, I would probably stick to the rules as written in this case, simply because getting to use those feats at range seems pretty good.